# Разбор кода для новичка

Tags: python

Для разбора кода, который не понимаю, использую [онлайн-репетитор](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), но у него ограничение в 100 строк. Какой использовать отладчик новичку для данных целей? Пробовал использовать pdb и eclipse, вызвали одно недоумение.

Comment: Вопрос, какой графический отладчик (GUI python debugger) можно использовать вроде http://winpdb.org, да?

Comment: Начинаю разбираться с Pycharm. Как использовать его для отображения стека и кучи Python? Как на этом сайте http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: Да никак. PyCharm не будет рисовать вам, как ваш визуализатор. Тут больше вопрос, зачем это нужно.

Comment: Нужно для понимания кода. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html здесь я видел, как питон работает с кодом, что куда сохраняет. Есть ли какие-либо инструменты, помогающие это сделать. Возможно, в другой интерпретации?

Comment: @arnold, учитесь интерпретировать в голове. Будете все время полагаться на всякие визуализации - не скоро продвинетесь в программировании.

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте PyCharm от JetBrains

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio + Python tools

Answer (score -1):

А чем вам стектрейс не нравится? Вообще не понятно, кто и зачем использует отладчики? Они бесполезны! Это равносильно заявлению "читайте только англоязычную документацию, в ней вы поймете больше" программистов, которые двух слов связать по-английски не могут! Не верьте никому! Трассировочная информация более чем дает представление об ошибках: где, когда и почему! Учитесь мыслить и иметь СВОЕ мнение!  Только так можно стать программистом!

Comment: 1. Мне кажется, или вы сейчас навязываете свое мнение?
2. Отладчик полезен например тем, что позволяет увидеть, что ваше представление о том, как работает код, отличается от того, как он на самом деле работает.

Comment: Единственная здравая мысль здесь:

    Учитесь мыслить и иметь СВОЕ мнение!

Частенько отладчик существенно ускоряет поиск ошибок. Установите точки останова  буквально в нескольких ключевых местах (да, для этого нужно подумать) и оцените значения переменных в них. 

Скорее всего вы увидите, что идет "не так", и без изучения длинных трасс.

Answer (score -2):

Полностью поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. Отладчики - это прошлый век (буквально). Ими пользуется сейчас полтора кодера на С++, учившихся в девяностых и остановившихся в своем развитии. А для динамических языков они вообще практически бесполезны. Используйте TDD, благо у Пайтона встроенный unittest есть.

```
from unittest import TestCase

def summator(a, b):
    pass

class TestSummator(TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual( summator(2, 2), 4 )
```

Потом запускаете в командной строке python.exe -m unittest discover и все! Вы покажите мне язык, в котором это все так же легко и просто, а главное - прямо из коробки. Я сейчас Nunit вспоминаю как страшный сон.

Объясняю вкратце, что такое TDD. Пишем вот такую функцию с пустым телом. Это нужно, во-первых, чтобы убедиться в функционировании окружения, а во-вторых, чтобы быть уверенным в отсутствии ложноположительных срабатываний. Потом пишем тело return 4, чтобы убедиться, что теперь тест проходит без ложноотрицательных срабатываний. Ну и наконец пишем нормальную функцию.

Comment: Не стоит так легко отказываться от полезных инструментов. Тесты покажут только то, что проблема есть, а отладчик может помочь в локализации проблемы.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы один пример того, как "отладчик может помочь в локализации проблемы"? Лучше, чем Traceback (most recent call last)...

Comment: @Xyanight, я не говорю, что что-то полезней, чем что-то другое. Трейсбэк тоже полезен, но только как один из инструментов. Трейсбек покажет, где проявилась проблема, но не укажет ее причину. Да и состояние программы в момент падения по нему не видно.

Comment: Как это "но не укажет ее причину"??? Укажет, покажет и ткнет носом! Мне иногда кажется, что программисты носятся с этими отладчиками, как бабы в ступе скорлупу толкут. Высасыват из пальца проблемы только потому, что кто-то когда-то начал использовать отладчик, мол, нынче модно голову заморачивать. Непонятно только отладчик чего? Кстати, мне (да и ТС, наверное) действительно хотелось бы посмотреть, как вы используете отладчик... Узнать, так сказать, врага в лицо. :)

Comment: @Xyanight, а что ТС, он не просто отладчик, он визуализатор использует, а это отладчик в квадрате, так что мы с ним скорее "по одну сторону" :)
Отладчиком практически не пользуюсь (разве что OllyDbg, но это из другой оперы), пользуюсь отладочным выводом. В любом случае продолжать дискуссия не имеет смысла.

Comment: @VadimTukaev: Мне кажется, вы слишком категоричны. Я знаю ещё одного человека, который пользуется отладчиком для отладки программ на C# даже в этом тысячелетии. То есть наверное хороший программист пишет сразу без ошибок (и даже без ошибок в unit-тестах), но существуют и обычные программисты, из мяса и костей.

Comment: Ответ VladD и insolor: Я не видел код, который требует отладки для "локализации проблемы" (например, код того сишарписта), но что-то мне подсказывает, что это очень плохой код. Хороший код - не обязательно безошибочный код. Я сам допускаю ошибки и в коде, и в тестах. Но в хорошем коде можно определить ошибку без отладки. Другими словами, если код не требует отладки - это еще не факт, что он хороший. Но если требует - это определенно плохой код.

Спросите того сишарписта, какова средняя длина его функций и методов. Если больше пяти строк, то неудивительно, что ему нужен отладчик для этой лапши

Comment: @VadimTukaev, похоже Вам пора обогатить плодами свого творчества [эту](http://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) или [эту](http://murphy-law.net.ru/programmers.html) странички.

--

Если серьезно, то думаю, что через десяток-другой как своих, так и прошедших через ваши руки чужих программ, взгляды на отладку здорово поменяются.

Comment: Спасибо за оказанное доверие, но моего творчества в этих словах немного. Это все говорилось много раз самыми разными людьми, гораздо более известными, чем ваш покорный слуга. Я просто повторяю то, с чем полностью согласен.

Надеюсь, взгляды у меня не поменяются. Давно прошли времена, когда требовалась отладка, комментарии и прочие костыли. Современные языки позволяют писать самоочевидный код, который объясняет компьютеру не КАК делать, а ЧТО делать. Потому он прост, короток и надежен.

Выполните это задание http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/yacht-or-dice-poker и посмотрите мое решение.

Comment: Такое чувство, что вы никогда не писали сложных программ и вам не приходилось реализовывать сложные алгоритмы, и TDD - это, конечно, хорошо, но совсем не серебряная пуля. Уже упоминалось, что тесты только помогают локализовать ошибку, но не найти и исправить её, а стектрейсы не помогают, если ошибка логическая, а не синтаксическая.